# wget command error in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, wget

I am trying to run below command using Jenkins shell:

```
wget -r --no-parent --reject "index.html*" http://${IP}/ranjans/ -P ${WORKSPACE}/tests
```

File is getting downloaded but my Jenkins job is marked failure. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Can you send us the console log? (with the wget command and the Jenkins failure)

Answer (score 0):

You might try looking at the no clobber option. I wonder if you are getting a bad result from wget because you are running this multiple times, and wget is complaining because the files already exist.

To double check that it is indeed wget that is failing, try printing out the exit value of wget. If it is 0, its a problem elsewhere.